# Render world space canvas first

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a canvas (in world space/3d) which is not showing to camera due to this shader which is applied to another (sphere) object.

```
Shader "Custom/TextureHolderCustom" {
    Properties {

        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Mask ("Mask Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

    }
    SubShader {
    Tags{"Queue" = "Transparent"}
       Cull Off
       Lighting On
       Zwrite On
       Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

       Pass
       {
       SetTexture[_Mask]{combine texture}
       SetTexture[_MainTex]{combine texture,previous}
       }
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

sphere object where my above shader is attached showing first but my canvas is not showing. I want to show the canvas first. I think i attach above shader to my canvas but it is not possible to apply m

*I am zero in shader programming*

Comment: To clarify: you have a worldspace canvas and a sphere with a shader on it. You want the *sphere* to render above the canvas regardless of position in space? Or you want the *canvas* to render above regardless of  position in space? Or something else? Can you provide a mockup of what you are trying to achieve and a screenshot of what you have currently?

Comment: I want that canvas which is in world space always render above my sphere object

Comment: Oh hey [Unity Answers has this exact question...with an answer!](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/878667/world-space-canvas-on-top-of-everything.html)